# Maintaining Configuration Files using .dll controls as ActiveX Control

Tags: c#, activex-exe

I need to create an ActiveX Control using .NET and I want to host it in a C++ application. I have created the ActiveX Control and one of the dependency controls using Enterprise Library 5.0. Now I need to maintain its respective configuration files.

When this control is hosted in a simple Windows Form it maintains all these configuration settings in a win forms app.config file.

Now my problem comes when I attempt to host this ActiveX .dll-file in C++, where and how do I need to maintain these configurations?

Comment: There's no scenario where a .config file can work properly in a COM component.  They are associated only with an .exe file, not a .dll